# Stream video from ios using kurento webrtc

Tags: ios, video, stream, webrtc, kurento

we have a website using Kurento webrtc to let peoples to broadcast videos with each other. Is it possible to stream video from ios device using same Kurento webrtc server. If yes do u know any resources or frameworks how to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Clone this demo application from https://github.com/nubomediaTI/Kurento-iOS and then update podfile.

Step 1: Open terminal and go to your target directory and type “pod install”

Step2:After successfully installation of pod open .workspace file and search “NSString *defaultWsRoom”  in the project . Replace the defaultWsRoom string with your current Kurento server Url.

Step3:Now run the application in the iOS device.